# Possible bug when using numpy.unique in conjunction with tkinter and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, tkinter

I'm building an application in Python using tkinter. The callback function for one of my GUI elements makes use of numpy.unique. Because it's very expensive, I run this function in a different thread to avoid holding up the GUI. If I do not provide the optional axis argument to numpy.unique, the program works as expected. However if I do provide this argument, the program behaves as if it's all running on the same thread.

The below code is a minimal example that demonstrates what I'm talking about. If the axis keyword argument is provided to np.unique, upon pressing the button the GUI is frozen until the button callback completes. If the axis argument is not provided, the GUI still works as expected while the button callback executes. Is this due to a bug in one of the modules I'm using or am I missing something?

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import tkinter as tk


def func(n):
    a = np.random.randint(256, size=(n, 3))
    np.unique(a, axis=0)
    print('done')


def callback():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(10**7,))
    thread.start()


root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Press me', command=callback)
button.pack()
scale = tk.Scale(root)
scale.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: I believe this problem is specifically related to tkinter somehow because the below code behaves as expected. Namely the final print statement is called prior to the termination of the function "func".

```
import numpy as np
import threading


def func(n):
    a = np.random.randint(256, size=(n, 3))
    np.unique(a, axis=0)
    print('done')


thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(10**7,))
thread.start()

print('This should print before func is done')
```

Comment: This is an implementation detail.  When you specify `axis=0`, `numpy` must do some of the computation in Python code instead of C code, and of course Python only allows one thread at a time to run Python code.

Comment: `unique` without axis flattens the array and uses `unique1d`.  That in turn depends heavily on `argsort`.  With axis, it makes a 1d structured array - and again uses `unique1d`.  The code is readable via the [source] link.  @TimRoberts, it's not obvious what's multithreadable c code, except maybe the `argsort` on numbers versus compound dtype records.  In any case , unique with axis is bound to be slower since it is comparing more complex objects.